# Proper approach for loading service json between two angular 1 controllers (only need to load resource once)

Tags: angularjs, json, service

I have two controllers we can call them controllerA and controllerB, they both share data from a service I made from watching guides and reading around. I'm not sure if what I'm seeing is correct and I may need a provider?

Here is My service :

```
angular.service("getJson", ['$http','$q', function($http,$q){
var deferred = $q.defer(); 

this.data = "";

$http.get('test.json')
.then(function(data){
  deferred.resolve(data);
});

this.getResource = function(){
  console.log("hey this has loaded!");
  return deferred.promise;
}

}]);`
```

Then in controllerA and ControllerB I load the promise I made. They are the same.

```
var jsonPromise = getJson.getResource();
jsonPromise.then(function(data){
  $scope.rowData = data;
})
```

I see in my console log the load happened twice! Is this what a provider is for? Isn't there a way to say, "HEY this loaded already don't load again here's the resource."

Comment: Yes getJson.getResource() will get called each time.  What specifically are you trying to avoid .... getJson.getResource() being called or the $http.get() being called or both?

Comment: You are already only making one server request and sharing the same promise

Comment: *"I see in my console log the load happened twice"* ... only because you call `getResource()` more than once. Move that `console.log()`  to `then()` of `$http` and will only see it once

Answer (score 0):

You could add some variable caching to the ´getJson´service method.
The first time you invokde the ´getJson´ method, the ´data´ var will be undefined, in that case the data is loaded. Else, the variable data is returned.

Quick example:

```
angular.service('getJson', function($http,$q) {
    // cache var
    var data;

    // service methods
    return {
        getResource: function(){ 
            // create promise
            var deferred = $q.defer(); 
            /* check cache */
            if(angular.isDefined(data)) {
                deferred.resolve(data); 
            } else {
                /* else load from http.get */
                $http.get('test.json').then(function(response){
                    deferred.resolve(response); 
                    data = response;
                });
            }
            // return promise
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
})
```

**Update returning 1 promise when same http.get is invoked simultaneously**

```
angular.service('getJson', function($http,$q) {
    // cache var
    var data;
    var curProm;
    var inProgress = false;

    // service methods
    return {
        getResource: function(){ 
            // check if in progress
            if(inProgress) return curProm;
            // create promise
            var deferred = $q.defer(); 
            /* check cache */
            if(angular.isDefined(data)) {
                deferred.resolve(data); 
            } else {
                // set progress
                inProgress = true;
                curProm = deferred;
                /* else load from http.get */
                $http.get('test.json').then(function(response){
                    deferred.resolve(response); 
                    data = response;
                    inProgress = false;
                });
            }
            // return promise
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: So how do you handle in controller when one condition returns a promise and the other doesn't?

Comment: I was toooo fast :) Check updated answer, both approaches resolve a promise :) Sorry

Comment: This won't prevent 2 simultaneous controllers in same view making multiple requests. Also should be `deferred.resolve(data)` in first;

Comment: Yes - as shown above - if(angular.isDefined(data)) {
                deferred.resolve(data); 
            } else {

Comment: Not if 2 requests get made before first is resolved. Usually not set up that way in view...but can be. In fact OP's code is sharing same promise and will only ever make one request

Comment: Shorter simpler version that removes `$q` anti-pattern https://plnkr.co/edit/67kVSHGw36t1tndrOjm3?p=preview